# Prove that a projector is continuous using Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, euclidean-geometry, vector-analysis

Given a vector $a$ in an Euclidean Space with $a\cdot a = 1$ ($\cdot$ = scalar product), then $P(b) = (a \cdot b)a$ defines the orthogonal projection $P$ on vector $a$.

How do you show that $P$ is **continuous** using ***Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality***?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple:
$$
Px - Px_0 = (a\cdot x)a - (a\cdot x_0)a = \left(a\cdot x - a\cdot x_0\right)a = \big(a\cdot(x-x_0)\big)a.
$$
Hence,
$$
\|Px - Px_0\| = |a\cdot(x-x_0)|\|a\| = |a\cdot(x-x_0)|.
$$
Now, use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: how does this show that P is continuous?

Comment: It even shows that $P$ is Lipschitz continuous. I will not explain this because I do not regard Math Stack Exchange as a service for complete solutions. You will have to do a little work yourself, but I can assist. So, what's your problem in seeing from the line above that $P$ is continuous? What is your definition of continuity?

Comment: If you use CS on the above to get an inequality, that inequality will making showing continuity with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition very easy.

Comment: To me continuity in the 1st and second dimension implies that for a point c, if I take the lim of my function and make it tend towards c it the limit would be f(c). I visualize it as drawing a straight line without taking my pen of the paper.
I have a difficult time geometrically interpreting continuity for higher dimensions in Rn.

Comment: So for every arbitrarly small e > 0 there exists an arbitrarly small d > 0 such that || x -a || < e implies || f(x) - f(a)|| < d

Comment: No. You have to swap e and d... Which inequality do you have after applying Cauchy Schwarz?